# Send email reply using powershell

Tags: email, powershell, gmail

I am using a powershell script to send an email using:

```
$smtpClient = New-Object System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient
$smtpClient.Host = 'smtp.gmail.com'
$smtpClient.Port = 587
$smtpClient.EnableSsl = $true
$smtpClient.Credentials = [Net.NetworkCredential](Get-Credential GmailUserID)
$smtpClient.Send($emailMsg)
```

Where $emailMsg is setup as:

```
$emailMsg = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage
$emailMsg.From = $YourEmail
$emailMsg.To.Add($RecipientEmail)
$emailMsg.Subject = $Subject
$emailMsg.Body = $body
$emailMsg.Attachments.Add("$PSScriptRoot\$AttachmentFile")
```

What I really need to be able to do is send a follow up email that will be a reply to this initial message, is there a way to do this through powershell?

Comment: Can you explain this a bit better? Reply from where?

Comment: @arco444 Sorry for the late reply got caught up in other work. Essentially i want to send out multiple emails to give information on an operation's progress, I would prefer the subsequent emails (sent from the same address) to show up as a reply to the initial email sent out. However I'm not sure if this is possible. I tried simply using "Re: $Subject" as the subject, however using gmail it doesnt come through as a reply.

Comment: Some info on gmail message threading here: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/965/how-does-gmail-decide-to-thread-email-messages

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a `In-Reply-To` header to your SMTP message. The value of the header should be the same as the value of the `Message-ID` header of the message that you wish to reply to.

```
$emailMsg.Headers.Add("In-Reply-To", "<id-of-prev-msg@mail.com>")
```

More information can be found at [Cognitive Buffet](http://wesmorgan.blogspot.co.uk/2012/07/understanding-email-headers-part-ii.html).